# SAS - How to select variables based on date within a date range?

Tags: sql, loops, date, sas, macros

Having a hard time figuring out the syntax for the following desire:

A table has 4 columns, predicted_sales_dt|predicted_sales_amt|actual_sales_dt|actual_sales_amt

My challenge is when creating a macro with a date range, i.e the current month, I want the column to be selected automatically based on the current date.

I tried a variation of between syntax ... most recently this one appeared logical, but doesn't work for obvious reasons (but trying to illustrate the desire mentioned above):

`

```
`if &start_dt.  < date() 
    or &end_dt. < date() then
    do;
        %let sales_dt=ACTL_SALES_DT;
        sales_dt_appld = "&sales_dt.";
    end;
else
    do;
        %let sales_dt=PRED_SALES_DT;
        sales_dt_appld = "&sales_dt.";
    end;`
```

`
Thus, any date before [today] should use actual info, and dates equal to today or later/future should use predicted info.

The problem with the above is obviously missing the [dates in between] the start and end date. I considered also using a proc sql select into option to then cycle through each of the dates in between the date range, but I am having a major mental road block. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why have the macro variable. What purpose could they serve that just typing the values wouldn't do?  Also since the macro code is evaluated before the data step starts the macro variable will always have PRED_SALES_DT in it when the data step runs.

Comment: Macro variable is for automation. No one is going to manually enter dates if the program is desired to be run daily/weekly/monthly/etc. The macro variable allows for one to create the respective dates... "next month" .. "last month" ... "two months from now" ... without having to constantly MANUALLY enter dates .....

If the program were to run today, the expectation is that 11/1/2022 through yesterday would use ACTUAL date/actual sales amt ... and TODAY through 11/30/2022 would use PREDICTED date and sales amt

Comment: If you want to pick which variable to reference based on data in the dataset used data step code, IF statement.  If you want to generate code based on vlaues of a macro variable then use macro code , %IF statement.  Make sure the code the macro logic generates is valid SAS code that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It does not like sound you need any macro logic for this problem.

So if START_DT has something that looks like a SAS date value. Perhaps a date literal.

```
 %let start_dt = '01JAN2020'd ;
```

Then you could use it in a data step to compare to other dates.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if &start_dt < date() then sales_dt= actual_sales_dt;
  else sales_dt = predicted_sales_dt;
run;
```

If the date value you are comparing to is not part of actual data, like your example of comparing to today's date, then you could use macro logic to generate the SAS code you want to run.

Remember the macro processor finishes its work first and passes the generated code to SAS to interpret and then the data step can run.

```
data want;
  set have;
%if %sysevalf(&start_dt < %sysfunc(date())) %then %do;
  sales_dt= actual_sales_dt;
%end;
%else %do;
  sales_dt = predicted_sales_dt;
%end;
run;
```

It might even be easier to use it to generate another macro variable you can use to generate the code.

```
%if %sysevalf(&start_dt < %sysfunc(date())) %then %let prefix= actual;
%else %let prefix= predicted;

data want;
  set have;
  sales_dt = &prefix._sales_dt;
  sales_amt = &prefix._sales_amt;
run;
```

Comment: The issue is applying this for a RANGE of dates, for use in a large dataset that has ... years of data. 

If the table has two columns with thousands of rows that contain dates, I want to select the respective column(s) contingent on what the date is the report is being run. So, let's say there are 2000 rows that happened before today, how do I ensure that all dates before today are assigned to a certain variable and all dates after today are assigned to a different variable?

If there are X amount of calendar days between the start date and end date I select, I need the logic to assess

Comment: I'm not sure if the issue is the way I am explaining the ask-- but EACH date in between TWO dates: start date and end date, needs to be compared to the system date (date report is run). Based on this, select the appropriate column/variable .. either Column X or Column Y depending on BEFORE today or AFTER today.

Comment: So that definitely sounds like something that does NOT need any macro logic.  Just normal SAS code.  You can just expand the macro variable with the date value in the place where it should go to form the test you want.  To get a real answer provide a complete description in the question. With example date values to make it clear.